# a square root of an irrational number

Tags: irrational-numbers

I wonder if a square root of an irrational number is always irrational?

I would tend to think that yes, but I can´t think of any justification. Also there are cases which are rather hard to decide like sqrt(Pi).

Comment: The square of a rational number is rational, so the square root of an irrational number must be irrational.

Comment: Great answer. How come I didn´t think of this? :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The square of a rational is rational, so the identity $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$ tells us that if the square root is rational, the original number must be too.